# How to include an exe with your pyqt5 application using fbs

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, exe, fbs

Looking to include an .exe file with my PyQt5 application so that changes made in the application can be sent to the .exe. The .exe file is a command line interface that needs to know a file location in order to find a document, or send that document to a server.

I've tried including it as a resource by storing it in the /resources directory and caching it using the @cache_property